# String operators not available in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

**Goal. (Sequelize v.3)**

Use a **select query** as a **subquery**. Final MySQL syntax should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE a_id IN (
    SELECT a_id
    FROM b
    WHERE b_something = 3
    and a_id IS NOT NULL
)
AND start_time
BETWEEN '2018-05-2015' AND '2019-12-01'
```

Read the docs for version 3 ([here](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/querying/#where) and [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v3/docs/docs/querying.md)) I should be able to use **string operators** like **$and**, **$ne**, etc. So I did the following:

```
// Where sequelize is the new Sequelize(configuration_here)
// and Sequelize is just the import Sequelize from 'sequelize";

const subquery = sequelize.dialect.QueryGenerator.selectQuery(
    'b',
    {
        attributes: ['a_id'],
        where: {
            [$and]:[
                {'b_something': key},
                {'a_id': {[$ne]: null}}
            ]
        }
    }
);

const final_query = await ModelA.findAll({
    where: {'a_id': sequelize.literal(`(${subquery})`)},
    logging: console.log
});
```

That is just not working at all. There's a **Reference Error: $and is not defined**.

I have also tried using **Sequelize.and** and **sequelize.and** they both are functions that seem to do what I want, but neither of these have the **ne** options. Also, I tried going for **Sequelize.Op** to view the operators, it prints a beautiful **UNDEFINED**.

I have been hours into this, and I can't figure out what I am messing up in. Using the **debugger** and printing both objects, I don't see any **Op** and the only operators I see are **and** and **or**.

I would really appreciate some help. Is the only way to do this just through a literal?

Comment: why are you keeping [$and] instead of $and? Try it

Comment: @Bibek put that as the answer and I'll mark it. I was obsessed with thinking that I had to place it within [] so it doesn't take the literal $and or $ne. I feel like such an idiot. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $and instead of [$and] . You won't make silly mistake again :)